# How to change file format from Unix to DOS using Perl?

Tags: perl, file, format

Basically I want to change my file format from Unix to DOS. Is there any way to do it in Perl? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

```
perl -Mopen=OUT,:crlf -pi.bak -e0 yourfilename
```

Comment: what does `-Mopen=OUT,:crlf` means?

Comment: @CharlesB: it is the command line equivalent to `use open 'OUT', ':crlf';` which makes output streams default to having a crlf layer (converting \n to \r\n).  See https://metacpan.org/pod/open

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dos2unix`/`unix2dos` commandline tools convert format to each other.

In `vim`, also it's simple.

You can read a file in DOS format and write it in Unix format.  This will
replace all `<CR><NL>` pairs by `<NL>` (assuming 'fileformats' includes "dos"): >

```
:e file
:set fileformat=unix
:w
```

If you read a file in Unix format and write with DOS format, all `<NL>`
characters will be replaced with `<CR><NL>` (assuming 'fileformats' includes
"unix"): >

```
:e file
:set fileformat=dos
:w
```